# IDX Workbench - Process Profiler

Tags: omnistudio

In the IDX Workbench - alpha version, the Process Profiler does not show "OmniScripts" under the component type. Tracking for OmniScripts is setup. Refresh data shows the error "Process Profiler Data Not Found" for any component type. The View in Org does not open the browser. What am I missing?

Comment: Can you check (https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.os_use_the_idx_workbench_process_profiler_59442.htm&type=5)

Comment: Hi Vinay, I followed the steps outlined and get the issues I described in my post.